# vbscript error on run command with long argument

Tags: vbscript

I need execute a script on vbs

I have no problem run the program.exe with this script

```
objShell.Run("%SystemDrive%\temp\program.exe")
```

However the program can support the arguement for silent installation

I run the following command manually on cmd is

```
%SystemDrive%\temp\program.exe /s /v"MS=1.1.1.1 SF= %SystemDrive%\temp\cert.ssl -l*v+! %temp%\install.log IP=False CFG="CFG_GRP" ICG="ICG_GRP" REBOOT=Force /qn""
```

so I put this command on the script but get exception error ')'

```
objShell.Run("%SystemDrive%\temp\program.exe /s /v"MS=1.1.1.1 SF= %SystemDrive%\temp\cert.ssl -l*v+! %temp%\install.log IP=False CFG="CFG_GRP" ICG="ICG_GRP" REBOOT=Force /qn""")
```

any idea?

Comment: You need to escape the quotes inside the string `"`. Wherever you have `"` you need to escape it like so `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Command = "cmd /c %SystemDrive%\temp\program.exe /s /v""MS=1.1.1.1 SF= %SystemDrive%\temp\cert.ssl -l*v+! %temp%\install.log IP=False CFG=""CFG_GRP"" ICG=""ICG_GRP"" REBOOT=Force /qn"""""
objShell.Run Command
```

or

```
objShell.Run "cmd /c %SystemDrive%\temp\program.exe /s /v""MS=1.1.1.1 SF= %SystemDrive%\temp\cert.ssl -l*v+! %temp%\install.log IP=False CFG=""CFG_GRP"" ICG=""ICG_GRP"" REBOOT=Force /qn"""""
```

Either way will work the issue is the incorrectly formed string.

Because quotes `"` denote the start and end of a string when used inside a string they have to be escaped by doubling them `""`, otherwise VBScript will think it's the end of the string and throw a syntax error.

Comment: screenshot of the error 

https://www.evernote.com/l/AATOy-pRz7hNbogjbaz-s4sQI7ZF0W9yJtcB/image.png

Comment: @Francis I've told you what you need to do, whether its a variable called `Command` or called directly in `objShell.Run()` is inconsequential. Infact you could just call `Command` in the `objShell.Run()`.

Comment: I have tried add 2 quote behind still get error, how to troubleshoot?

Comment: @Francis have you actually tried the code I've posted, looking at the question you are still not getting that all the quotes need to be escaped! Its even obvious when you look at the syntax highlighting because its not a properly constructed string.

Comment: Hi @Lankymart, the same script no issue run on windows 2008 but error happen in windows 2012, any idea what might wrong 

error "the system cannot find the file specified"


https://www.evernote.com/l/AAQj7Ujr7uJElqWGNB3ZXtyeLDCbf54_a5IB/image.png

Comment: @Francis In which case post a new question detailing the error you get in Windows 2012 and we will try to help.

Comment: @Francis Sounds like the path might not be working, may be Windows 2012 doesn't support the environment variables you are using `%SystemDrive%`, `%temp%` but that is highly unlikely. Are you sure the file is in the same place on the Windows 2012 server and the script has execute rights to it?

Comment: Hi @Lankymart after troubleshoot find out the problem with the 7z.exe after replace with 7za.exe thing are working fine, no issue with the code