# Not able to launch bat file form VBScript if path contains a space

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, path, filepath

I have been trying to launch myFileToRun.bat file from a path for example.

```
D:\My Folder\batchfiles\myFileToRun.bat
```

Below is the VBScript through which I'm trying to run it.

```
Dim WshShell, strCurrentDirectory  
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
strCurrentDirectory    = WshShell.CurrentDirectory  
WshShell.Run strCurrentDirectory & "\myFileToRun.bat" , 0  
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I'm not able to run it, as VBS is thowing error sayin "System cannot find the file specified"
I have tried various methods mentioned in other similar posts in stackoverflow and other forums. Most of them say to add double quotes.

Note: I have tried adding double quotes, double double quotes for example

```
1.WshShell.Run """strCurrentDirectory & "\myFileToRun.bat" "", 0
2.WshShell.Run """"strCurrentDirectory & "\myFileToRun.bat"""", 0
3.WshShell.Run """"strCurrentDirectory & \myFileToRun.bat"""", 0
```

None of them worked as I guess I am giving quotes at wrong places. The variable strCurrentDirectory changes to "strCurrentDirectory" instead of "D:\My Folder\batchfiles" and so my final path would be "strCurrentDirectory""\myFileToRun.bat", which is wrong. I need the path to be "D:\My Folder\batchfiles\myFileToRun.bat" and the file to run.

I haven't really understood the concept of these adding quotes.
So can you please explain me this concept and help me in resolving this error.

Edit: I have got the solution. As I had to refer to the current directory, I just made the script simpler.

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "myFileToRun.bat", 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Thank you all for your answers. It was helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vbscript error on run command with long argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503447/vbscript-error-on-run-command-with-long-argument)

Comment: You just need to escape any quotes you want as part of the argument, you do this by doubling them `""`. Your attempts don't work because you forget to concatenate the string *(that's why the variable `strCurrentDirectory` get's added as part of the string instead of it's value)*, try this - `WshShell.Run """" & strCurrentDirectory & "\myFileToRun.bat""", 0`

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
Dim WshShell, strCurrentDirectory  
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
strCurrentDirectory    = WshShell.CurrentDirectory  
WshShell.Run """" & strCurrentDirectory & "\di r\myFileToRun.bat" & """" , 0  
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: What's with the `& """"` on the end?, no need to concatenate there just do `WshShell.Run """" & strCurrentDirectory & "\di r\myFileToRun.bat""", 0`.

Comment: Which that does...end of the day it's just a string `& """"` does nothing that `"""` doesn't.

Comment: @Lankymart  - ahh correct. Eventually could be used if the bat file name is set as variable.

Comment: That is indeed true.

Comment: @npocmaka It's working fine, the error is gone now. Appreciate your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to escape the quotes in the string correctly, the rule is whenever you want to show a quote in a string double it.

So, this command

```
WshShell.Run strCurrentDirectory & "\myFileToRun.bat" , 0
```

At the moment will be passed as;

```
D:\My Folder\batchfiles\myFileToRun.bat
```

As with most Windows programs paths with spaces need to be surrounded with quotes when passed to ensure the full path is recognised, at the moment `Run()` is seeing

```
D:\My
```

and the rest as an argument passed to the `My` program. As the system won't be able to find the `My` program it will cause the

> System cannot find the file specified

error.

To fix this we need to pass a quoted string *(doubling the quotes for each literal quote we want to include)*

```
WshShell.Run """" & strCurrentDirectory & "\myFileToRun.bat""", 0
```

which will be passed as;

```
"D:\My Folder\batchfiles\myFileToRun.bat"
```

> **Note:** When concatenating with variables we still need to open and close the string correctly. For a situation like above we concatenate the string `""""` on to a variable, which is simply `""` but with a opening and closing quote to denote the literal string.

Also variables need to be correctly concatenated to the string or you will get weird results, for example your first attempt to escape the string

```
WshShell.Run """strCurrentDirectory & "\myFileToRun.bat" "", 0
```

would cause;

> Expected end of statement

because it isn't a correctly terminated string.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in such detail. Got a clear understanding.

Comment: @VikasVicky No problem glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to add double quotes into variables :

```
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
```

So, the code becomes easy for reading :

```
Dim WshShell, strCurrentDirectory  
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
strCurrentDirectory = WshShell.CurrentDirectory  
wscript.echo DblQuote(strCurrentDirectory & "\My Folder\myFileToRun.bat")
WshShell.Run DblQuote(strCurrentDirectory & "\My Folder\myFileToRun.bat"),0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
'********************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'********************************************************************
```

Comment: I have tried that and It will still throw the error as strCurrentDirectory will be considered as a literal and path would become "strCurrentDirectory"\myFileToRun.bat

Comment: That won't work because the `DblQuote()` function needs to be `DblQuote = Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34) & Chr(34)`, your not doubling the quotes.

Comment: @VikasVicky When you execute this : `wscript.echo DblQuote(strCurrentDirectory & "\My Folder\myFileToRun.bat")` What did you get as result ?

Comment: @Lankymart actually the `DblQuote()` function is working without double double quotes.

Comment: @Hackoo I guess I wasn't calling the function properly. It's working fine now. Thank you. It displays the path properly as `"D:\My Folder\batchfiles\myFileToRun.bat"`

Comment: @VikasVicky ah, yeah just tested myself because it uses the `Chr(34)` method to define the ASCII character it doesn't interfere with the string definition.

Answer (score -2):

Have tried all the above methods for VBScript files that work OK on a Windows 7 PC and fail miserably on a Windows 10  PC.
VBScript accepts spaces within strings, but NOT in the "run" method.
Scripts with lines such as

wss = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wss.run = "C:\Program Files\xxx.exe"

will fail miserably. In this case the solution is easy:
you define a link to xxx, xxx.lnk, store it in a folder with no spaces in the path, for example

C:\Users\Links

and then in VBScript use

wss.run = "C:\Users\Links\xxx.lnk"

This will work, but for some more complicated VBScripts the reworking can be major. Pity.
A bug is a bug.