# Run programs with too many spaces

Tags: vbscript, spaces

I have a command that works fine with command prompt:

```
CMD /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep""
```

Here I need `CMD /C` to return the errorlevel.

That's how I tried to run this in VBScript using `Run` method:

```
WshShell.Run "CMD /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep""", 0, False
```

This command throws the following error:

> Expected end of statement (Char: 74)

I saw many similar questions about running programs with spaces in its and its parameters' paths. I tried changing above command into hundreds of different commands with adding more double quotation marks into different positions as I saw in answers, but nothing worked and everytime I ran the script, one of the following errors occured:

> Expected end of statement
>   The system cannot find the file/path specified (null)
>   Unterminated string constant
>   Expected ")"
>   Expected "("

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to launch bat file form VBScript if path contains a space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254375/not-able-to-launch-bat-file-form-vbscript-if-path-contains-a-space)

Comment: Your not escaping the double quotes. When used in VBScript all double quotes that appear inside a string need to be escaped, you do this by doubling them *(`""`)*. See the [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37254929/692942) for breakdown of how it should be done.

Comment: The command should have been `WshShell.Run "CMD /C """"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC"" -vvv ""http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO=="" :sout=#file{dst=""F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4"",no-overwrite} :sout-keep""""", 0, False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lankymart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43650997/3439404) is right:

> You just need to escape the quotes in the string correctly, the rule
>   is whenever you want to show a quote in a string double it.

However, you still have unbalanced double quotes in the original code (a surplus trailing `"`).

```
WshShell.Run "CMD /C """"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC"" -vvv ""http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO=="" :sout=#file{dst=""F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4"",no-overwrite} :sout-keep"""
```

This will run as

```
CMD /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep"
```

**Sample VBScript** (a particular executable `cliparserPause.exe` is used to *mimic* `VLC` behaviour):

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim sCmdToRun, WshShell, intReturn

' CMD /C ""D:\bat\Prog Files (x86)\cliparserPause.exe" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep"
sCmdToRun = "CMD /C """"D:\bat\Prog Files (x86)\cliparserPause.exe"" -vvv ""http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO=="" :sout=#file{dst=""F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4"",no-overwrite} :sout-keep"""
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & sCmdToRun

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
intReturn = WshShell.Run( sCmdToRun, 1, true)
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & Cstr( intReturn )

Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit( intReturn )
```

**Output**:

```
==> CMD /C ""D:\bat\Prog Files (x86)\cliparserPause.exe" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C
 Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep"
param 0 = D:\bat\Prog Files (x86)\cliparserPause.exe
param 1 = -vvv
param 2 = http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==
param 3 = :sout=#file{dst=F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4,no-overwrite}
param 4 = :sout-keep
press any key to continue...

==> echo %errorlevel%
-1004

==> cscript //NOLOGO D:\VB_scripts\SO\43649265.vbs
43649265.vbs
CMD /C ""D:\bat\Prog Files (x86)\cliparserPause.exe" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C Bac
kup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep"
-1004

==> echo %errorlevel%
-1004
```

**cliparserPause.exe** source:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <wchar.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        wprintf(L"param %d = %S\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    wprintf(L"press any key to continue...");
    std::getchar();
    exit(-999 - argc);  /* exitcode to OS = ( -1000 -supplied_paramaters_count ) */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good spot, I hadn't tested it just assumed as the OP said the command worked from the command prompt the escaping was the only issue.

Comment: @Lankymart the command works as  `cmd` _throws away_ that unbalanced trailing `"` by itself. It's merely my hairsplitting…

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks all, should I choose "That solved my problem" or leave it?

Comment: Nice application "cliparserPause" :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254929/692942) you would realise that none of the double quotes in your string are escaped.

> <sup>From [A: Not able to launch bat file form VBScript if path contains a space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254929/692942)</sup>
> *You just need to escape the quotes in the string correctly, the rule is whenever you want to show a quote in a string double it.*

So the line should be

```
WshShell.Run "CMD /C """"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC"" -vvv ""http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSig‌n=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC‌8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO=="" :sout=#file{dst=""F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4"",no-overwrite} :sout-keep""""", 0, False
```

Which will run as

```
CMD /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSig‌n=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC‌​8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep""
```

---

#### Update

[@JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) has rightly pointed out in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43652798/692942) that the original command has an unnecessary trailing double quote *(`"`)*, so although the rule is correct to get the right result the original command you are trying to escape needs to be correct. I made an assumption based off this from your question;

> *"I have a command that works fine with command prompt"*

The original command should have been

```
CMD /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep""
```

which using this method would be

```
WshShell.Run "CMD /C """"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC"" -vvv ""http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSig‌n=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC‌8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO=="" :sout=#file{dst=""F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4"",no-overwrite} :sout-keep""", 0, False
```

and result in being executed as

```
CMD /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC" -vvv "http://www.foo.com:8085/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9NC8yNy8yMDE3IDEyO==" :sout=#file{dst="F:\\Partition C Backup\\Downloads\\Video\\TESTING.mp4",no-overwrite} :sout-keep"
```

Comment: Very nice, Thank you, as you all say the double - quotation mark I added at the end of the original command is surplus and unnecessary, I checked and even CMD runs the command with and without it, even runs with three double - quotation marks. I think commands are exactly same with or without that surplus trailing. :-)