# Filename string space issue in VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I get an error when I run this command and I am unsure why.

Running VBScript to execute a bat file, I want to output any error messages to a log file. So to do this I have the code:

```
Set WshShell =  CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "cmd /k ""C:\ProgramTHISSTRING Files (x86)\Folder\File.bat"" > ""C:\Program Files(x86)\Folder\File.txt""", 1, True
```

(I do have the code to do this more elegantly but for the purpose of the problem, I think this reads better and quicker)

Also I have put in THISSTRING on purpose for the error below.

Once this executes I get this error in CMD

> 'C:\ProgramTHISSTRING' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I understand it's a space in the file name that has caused the error, however, I have the right quotes according to 
[this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360599/vbs-with-space-in-file-path) so why is this error happening?

Comment: Did you [not see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43652798/692942) from yesterday, still shows on the first page?

Comment: Think you'll need to wrap the whole command passed to `cmd /k` in quotes so it will be `WshShell.Run "cmd /k """"C:\ProgramTHISSTRING Files (x86)\Folder\File.bat"" > ""C:\Program Files(x86)\Folder\File.txt""""", 1, True` which will run as `"cmd /k ""C:\ProgramTHISSTRING Files (x86)\Folder\File.bat" > "C:\Program Files(x86)\Folder\File.txt""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is because the `cmd /k` needs the commands passed to it to be encapsulated in double quotes.

So the command *(removed `THISSTRING` as you said that was just to trigger the error)*

```
WshShell.Run "cmd /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\File.bat"" > ""C:\Program Files(x86)\Folder\File.txt""", 1, True
```

Becomes

```
WshShell.Run "cmd /k """"C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\File.bat"" > ""C:\Program Files(x86)\Folder\File.txt""""", 1, True
```

and run's as

```
cmd /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\File.bat" > "C:\Program Files(x86)\Folder\File.txt""
```